# Windows Phone Authentication? PubCenter Ad app creation?

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, windows-phone-8

I just started Windows Phone app development and my app is making a fair amount of money via advertisements (through PubCenter). I really like Microsoft's Dev Center app for Windows Phone but they don't have an app that allows you to check your advertisement statistics. I wanted to initially make one for personal use then, if polished enough, publish one. The problem is I've never done anything like this. Is it even possible? I looked at the source on the reports page and see where I could extract today's and this month's earnings, but I don't know where I'd start regarding authentication. Could someone please point me in the right direction? (or shut me down if it isn't possible)

Here's the link in question - https://pubcenter.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea about a month ago but then backed off because I was to lazy to implement it. Here's the API resource I found. I look forward to seeing it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983013.aspx

-RT Apps